# Set specific color type intable cell

Tags: css

is it possible to directly style if a cell contains a specific string?
for an example

```
<td>red</td>
<td>red</td>
<td>green</td>
<td>red</td>
<td>gree</td>
<td>yellow</td>
```

I know that this is achievable by nth-type but assuming that there thousands of rows, are we able to set something like

css style

```
td:contains(red) {
background: red;
}
```

i am trying not to use javascript but plain css script.

Comment: It's not possible but you could add a class to all those cells that contain 'red'

Comment: there's no way what you want with only `CSS`

Comment: If you can render that `HTML` dynamically with `javascript` you can add `class` each table cell.

Answer (score 0):

**There's no way to do it by using css only**

JS code if you are interested:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach( td => {
    if(td.innerText.contains("your text")){
      td.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
});
```